# Pushstate on React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to refresh the react component route on history pushState?

For ex :

```
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="/search/:query/" component={search}/>
 </Route>

 this.props.history.pushState(null,"/search/test");
```

Suppose if i am on the search route itself, and in my code am pushing the state,is it possible to refresh the route?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, and it's not something the react-router maintainers are planning to support since that's not how react works (i.e. only if virtual dom changes will react reload the component). See this [thread](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1982) for the context of the discussion.

> Angular blows everything away and reinitializes all of it. React will do a virtual DOM diff. None of your willMount, didMount etc. hooks will be called. But you'll get "already mounted" hooks like componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidUpdate.
>
> There could be 2,000 people asking for this feature to try to reload their data, but React (not React Router) just doesn't work that way.